# UIBarButtonItem tint not working in 6.1 app on iOS7 device

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I have a view controller that adds a button to the navigation bar with orange tint color.

```
UIBarButtonItem *bt = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithTitle:@"Call Us" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(callUsPressed:)];

bt.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(247/255.0) green:(151/255.0) blue:(48/255.0) alpha:1.0];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bt;
```

This works fine in iOS6.1 device. That is, the button shows up orange.

[image]

In iOS7 device, the button first shows up as blue.

[image]

When I tap on it, the button becomes orange.

[image]

The app is compiled against iOS 6.1 SDK. Is this is a bug in iOS7 or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you include a picture on how it looks on ios 7?

Comment: Can you try changing the order?  Adding the button first, then setting the tint color?  Possibly try setting the tintColor in `viewDidLoad` if you're not.  6.1 SDK support in iOS 7 is far from perfect so tweaking the order may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 7's handling of iOS 6.1 UI elements.  I've tried a number of ways and cannot reliably set a `UIBarButtonItem` tint color.  Setting the color after it is added to the navigation item in `viewDidLoad` works for the first screen but not later screens.  You can do it in `viewDidAppear:` but you end up with blue during the animation.

Your best bet is to set the tint color on the navigation bar itself, and then if you need the bar to look different, set its background image.

Comment: I have a problem with iOS7 not putting background image on UIBarButtonItem, only on iPad, I cannot tell if I am doing something wrong or if it could be a bug, see: [UIBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage not working anymore in iOS7 iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235804/uibarbuttonitem-setbackgroundimage-not-working-anymore-in-ios7-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(247/255.0) green:(151/255.0) blue:(48/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

Add this to your code.

Comment: This will change the tin of the whole navigation bar. I want to change the tint of a bar button.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I think I have arrived at a workaround.  I discovered this solution because I had some interesting behaviors that would toggle the color of buttons that would work, but setting the button tint directly in viewDid/Will/whatever would not work.  The difference appears to be that the buttons had to be created and set on the navigationItem sometime after viewDidLoad was called.

Long story short, recreating the button, setting the button tint, and updating the navigationItem in the following UINavigationControllerDelegate method did the trick:

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

In order to make this as transparent to my app as possible, I used the following delegate that would look for a method in the view controller and call it at the right time:

iOS7ButtonTintWorkAround.h:

```
@interface RMSiOS7ButtonTintWorkAround : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) RMSiOS7ButtonTintWorkAround* preventGC;

- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController;

@end
```

iOS7ButtonTintWorkAround.m:

```
#import "iOS7ButtonTintWorkAround.h"

@implementation iOS7ButtonTintWorkAround

NSObject<UINavigationControllerDelegate>* _delegate;


- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _delegate = [navigationController delegate];
        [navigationController setDelegate:self];
        _preventGC = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(_delegate) {
        [_delegate navigationController:navigationController willShowViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    }
}

- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(_delegate) {
        [_delegate navigationController:navigationController willShowViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    }

    if([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(iOS7SetBarButtonTint)]) {
        [viewController performSelector:@selector(iOS7SetBarButtonTint)];
    }
}
@end
```

Because the delegate property is not a strong reference, it is necessary to do something to prevent the delegate from being GC'd.  I don't create that many UINavigationControllers so I can live with the leak, but if anyone can suggest a way to keep the delegate alive only as long as its UINavigationController, I'd be interested to know it?